# What is a general way to find an oblique asymptote from a function?

Tags: calculus

What is a general way to find an oblique asymptote from a function? How do you find the slope and intercept of the asymptote from the function?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

An oblique asymptote is of the form $y=mx+b$. So you want to find $m$ and $b$ such that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}[f(x)-(mx+b)]=0.$$
Similarly you can deal with $x \to -\infty$.

**Added explanation**

The values of $m$ and $b$ will depend on the function $f$.  For example, if $f(x)=\frac{x^2-x+2}{x+3}$, then
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)-(mx+b)=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x^2\color{red}{(1-m)}+x\color{blue}{(-1-3m-b)}+(2-3b)}{x+3}.$$
As $x \to \infty$, we want this limit to go to $0$. For that to happen, we should have coefficients of both $x^2$ and $x$ be $0$. That means we should have $m=1$ and $-1-3m-b=0$, Thus $m=1$ and $b=-4$. So $y=x-4$ is an oblique asymptote.

Comment: Thanks. How do you find this m and b? What m and b do you choose?

Comment: @Deadpool36701 I have added some more explanation, see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! How do you know in advance that there will be a m and a b? Is there a theorem that can tell us the conditions for which function will have an oblique asymptote?

Comment: @Deadpool36701 for a general function it is hard to give a rule that fits all scenarios (other than what I have stated or the equivalent answer given by "marwalix"). But for rational functions (poly/poly), one can say that if the numerator degree is one more than the denominator degree then such an $m$ and $b$ will exist.

Answer (score 0):

if they exist one has

$$\begin{align}
m=&\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)\over x}\\
b=&\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(f(x)-mx \right)
\end{align}$$

So you start by looking at the first limit and if it exists you look at the second

Comment: If you compute those 2 limits and you find they do not exist, then that means the function has no oblique asymptote?

Comment: You cannot compute the second limit if you don’t know the first one or if the first one doesn't exist. So you start by finding $m$. If $m$ exists you have an asymptotic direction. If $b$ exists you have an oblique asymptote